# c++ visual studio compiler OpenMP

Tags: c++, windows, openmp

I'm trying to compile a source code on Windows that works great on Linux.
Now, I'm facing the following issue:

The code relies on OpenMP and in there, the scheduling approach should be stored in a string and the chunk size in an integer.

The following code does extract the necessary information.

```
omp_sched_t omp_sched;
int chunkSize;
omp_get_schedule( &omp_sched, &chunkSize );

string jobScheduling;
switch ( omp_sched ) {
    case omp_sched_static:
        jobScheduling = "static";
        break;
    case omp_sched_dynamic:
        jobScheduling = "dynamic";
        break;
    case omp_sched_guided:
        jobScheduling = "guided";
        break;
    case omp_sched_auto:
        jobScheduling = "auto";
        break;
    default:
        jobScheduling = "auto";
        break;
}
```

On Windows, by using the Microsoft Visual Studio compilers, it does not recognize `omp_sched_t`, `omp_sched_static`, `omp_sched_dynamic`...

Is this Linux specific? If not, how can I fix this (preferably without changing the source code)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using features introduced in OpenMP 3.0 but Microsoft VisualC++ only supports OpenMP 2.0. And, AFAIK, even that support is deprecated though it's still there.

If you want support for modern OpenMP, you simply need a different compiler. Visual Studio comes with optional Clang, which has the required support, but enabling OpenMP via the Project Properties dialog can be a bit tricky. Another option is Intel C/C++ Compiler for Windows, which is a commercial piece of software.

Comment: GCC should also work, and, while you are right that Intel compilers are commercial, they're also gratis for many people. (AFAICS the newly packaged oneAPI version is free to everyone and includes OpenMP compilers https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/tools/oneapi/hpc-toolkit.html [though maybe also a bunch of stuff you didn't want :-)])

Comment: @JimCownie the oneAPI compiler was "beta" the last time I checked it (in Q1 of this year), although it seemed pretty solid to me. So now the old compiler has become the Classic one and the oneAPI one is where all the fun is?

Comment: @hristolliev I believe that you are correct; all the fun (and future development) will be in the LLVM based oneAPI compilers. I haven't worked at Intel since June last year, so don't know schedules, but they are certainly saying "Gold Intel® oneAPI Toolkits Ship in December 2020" (https://techdecoded.intel.io/resources/intel-oneapi-beta-releases/#:~:text=Gold%20Intel%C2%AE%20oneAPI%20Toolkits%20Ship%20in%20December%202020)

Comment: OneAPI compilers seem now to be available (and free). https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/tools/oneapi.html

Comment: @JimCownie good, I thought they were going to be perpetually in beta :D